# Run linux command from jenkins job

Tags: bash, jenkins

Im trying to run bash command from jenkins job:

```
role = "bla"
query = "exceptions | where (cloud_RoleName == '${role}') | summarize _count=sum(itemCount) by type"

                  
command = "az monitor app-insights query --app ${application} --resource-group {resourceGroup} --analytics-query \"${query}\" --offset 12h"
```

But i cannot get this to work since its either replacing " with ' or ' with '"'

```
+ az monitor app-insights query --app BlaBla --resource-group Bla --analytics-query 'exceptions | where (cloud_RoleName == '"'"'bla'"'"') | summarize _count=sum(itemCount) by type' --offset 12h
```

Tried escaping with `\` but nothing seems to work

Any idea?

Comment: Seems to work fine on Git Bash: role="bla"; 
query="'${role}'"; 
command="\"${query}\""; 
echo $role; `bla`
echo $query; `'bla'`
echo $command; `"'bla'"`

Comment: What you see in Jenkins Console Output is the [trace output](https://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_03.html). You can enable it on your console via `set -x`.

Comment: Trace output: set -x; 
echo $role; 
`+ echo bla` 
echo $query; 
`+ echo ''\''bla'\'''` 
echo $command; 
`+ echo '"'\''bla'\''"'`

Comment: Another observation from your code: There's space before and after = sign. [Variable assignment](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/varassignment.html) in Bash shouldn't have space before and after = sign.